# Adding OR-Tools Library to Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019, or-tools

I am trying to write a code using Google's OR-Tools library on Microsoft Visual Studio 2019. I followed the following steps:

1. Installed OR-Tools from Binary on Windows on their website.
2. Extracted the .zip file in C:\Libraries
3. Wrote my code on VS (I wrote #include <ortools/linear_solver/linear_solver.h> and using namespace operations_research; rest is usual C++ Code)
4. In Visual Studio, went to Project > Properties > C/C++ > Additional Include Directories
5. Added "C:\Libraries\or-tools\include" (which contains the folder "ortools" that I included)
6. Clicked Apply then OK then compiled my code.

I am getting a bunch of linking errors "error LINK2019". Is there anything else I should do so I can use this library freely on my machine?

Answer (score 2):

From the supplied makefile:

Compile flags:

```
  DEBUG = /O2 -DNDEBUG
  CXXFLAGS = /std:c++17 /EHsc /MD /nologo /D_SILENCE_STDEXT_HASH_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS -nologo $(DEBUG) \
    /DPSAPI_VERSION=1 /D__WIN32__ /DNOMINMAX /DWIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN=1 /D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS \
    /DGFLAGS_DLL_DECL= /DGFLAGS_DLL_DECLARE_FLAG= /DGFLAGS_DLL_DEFINE_FLAG= /DGOOGLE_GLOG_DLL_DECL= \
    /I$(INC_DIR)\\src\\windows /I$(INC_DIR) /I. \
    /DUSE_BOP /DUSE_GLOP \
    /DUSE_CBC /DUSE_CLP \
    /DUSE_SCIP
```

Link flags:

```
  LDFLAGS = psapi.lib ws2_32.lib
  OR_TOOLS_LNK = lib\\ortools.lib
```

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: Update: There's 1 .lib file in that directory, I tried adding it in Properties > Linker > Input > Additional Dependencies and I also added its path "C:\Libraries\or-tools\lib" in Properties > Linker > General > Additional Library Directories. But I am still getting the same linking errors.