# Unresolved external symbol error (LNK2019) ORTools

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, constraint-programming, or-tools

I have tried to run this code:

```
#include "ortools/include/ortools/base/logging.h"
#include "ortools/include/ortools/constraint_solver/constraint_solver.h"

using namespace operations_research;
    void RunConstraintProgrammingExample() {
    // Instantiate the solver.
    Solver solver("ConstraintProgrammingExample");
    const int64 numVals = 3;

    // Define decision variables.
    IntVar* const x = solver.MakeIntVar(0, numVals - 1, "x");
    IntVar* const y = solver.MakeIntVar(0, numVals - 1, "y");
    IntVar* const z = solver.MakeIntVar(0, numVals - 1, "z");

    // Define constraints.
    std::vector<IntVar*> xyvars = { x, y };
    solver.AddConstraint(solver.MakeAllDifferent(xyvars));

    // Create decision builder to search for solutions.
    std::vector<IntVar*> allvars = { x, y, z };
    DecisionBuilder* const db = solver.MakePhase(
        allvars,
        Solver::CHOOSE_FIRST_UNBOUND,
        Solver::ASSIGN_MIN_VALUE);

    bool has_result = solver.Solve(db);
    // Check that the problem has a solution.
    if (has_result != true) {
        //LOG(FATAL) << "The problem does not have a solution!";
    }
    int count = 0;
    while (solver.NextSolution()) {
        count++;
        //LOG(INFO) << "Solution " << count << ":";
        //LOG(INFO) << "x = " << x->Value()
           // << " ; y = " << y->Value()
            //<< " ; z = " << z->Value();
    }
    //LOG(INFO) << "Number of solutions: " << count;
    //LOG(INFO) << "";
    //LOG(INFO) << "Advanced usage:";
    //LOG(INFO) << "Problem solved in " << solver.wall_time() << "ms";
}
// namespace operations_research 

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    //google::InitGoogleLogging(argv[0]);
    //FLAGS_logtostderr = 1;
    RunConstraintProgrammingExample();
    return 0;
}
```

but I get 9 unresolved external symbol errors (LNK2019)

Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall operations_research::Solver::Solver(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits,class std::allocator > const &)" (??0Solver@operations_research@@QAE@ABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl RunConstraintProgrammingExample(void)" (?RunConstraintProgrammingExample@@YAXXZ)

I have tried to put into additional include directories of the project the include file from ortools and I have also tried to put the ortools lib into the linker input in properties. Still didn't work. I also tried to modify it to x64 put then I get 200 or so errors. What else can I try?

Answer (score 2):

You need to compile with c++ 17.

You can have a look at this post:

[Adding OR-Tools Library to Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65559940/adding-or-tools-library-to-visual-studio)

Comment: and unless you are using the routing library, do not use the old constraint solver. Use the CP-SAT one instead.

Comment: I tried compiling with c++ 17 and got rid of those errors but now I have:
'std::allocator<std::pair<const K,V> >::rebind<U>' errors (C4996)

Comment: Look at the supplied makefiles. All the options are there.

Comment: I don't understand where I compile and link those flags. Do I just need to copy-paste that code and compile?

Comment: You need to reverse engineer compile and link flags from the previous posts into visual projects parameters.

Comment: I have tried to add the compiler flags under project -> c/c++ -> command line and it doesn't work. Could you guide me with the steps of how to link the flags from your previous post?

Comment: I do not use visual studio. You are on your own.